# How can I display my json object with TypeScript in Angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to display my json array in html using *ngFor but I believe it's not working because it needs to be inside the class AppComponent.  But if I try to move the source code to make the json object inside the AppComponent class I get an error.

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  s = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
  myHero = this.s[0];

}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  year: number; 
}

var people: Person[] = [{ name: 'robert', year: 1993 }];
var newPerson: Person = { name: 'joe', year: 1992 };

people.push(newPerson);

newPerson = {name: 'jose', year: 1997};

people.push(newPerson);


console.log(people[2].name);
```

This is my app.component.html file

```
<p>HEllo</p>


<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let name of s">
    {{ name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to do something to what I did in the html file but with the other array

Comment: Can you show us **how** you do it with the other array on your html? And what's the `error` you encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to treat the app component like a class. This shouldn't throw any errors.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
interface Person {
  name: string;
  year: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public s = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
  public myHero = this.s[0];
  public people : Person[];
  public newPerson: Person;

  constructor() {
    this.people = [{ name: 'robert', year: 1993 }];
    this.newPerson = { name: 'joe', year: 1992 };

    this.people.push(newPerson);

    this.newPerson = {name: 'jose', year: 1997};

    this.people.push(newPerson);


    console.log(this.people[2].name);
  }

}
```

Comment: The constructor isn't the best place to initialize data; use the `ngOnInit` life-cycle hook provided by angular.

Comment: Yeah it should probably be broken out into meaningful functions. My answer is just to show him how to get it working without errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the statements within a method/constructor of a class which you are not doing, hence the compile time error. The `ngOnInit()` is the ideal place for your component to *initialize* its data.

Your component should look something like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  people: Person[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.people  = [{ name: 'robert', year: 1993 }];
    let newPerson: Person = { name: 'joe', year: 1992 };
    this.people.push(newPerson);
    newPerson = {name: 'jose', year: 1997};
    this.people.push(newPerson);
    console.log(this.people[2].name);
  }
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  year: number; 
}
```

And the template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let p of people">
    {{ p.name }}, {{ p.year }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mt8ly6) for the same.